# Syntax Errors During Implementation of a Service

Tags: java, android, service, syntax, syntax-error

I'm attempting to create a service which is capable of byteswapping the MDN of a device however I'm getting several syntax errors when I'm attempting to do so. I've been told this is not possible - however I'd like a bit of help proving my co-worker wrong.

At the moment - I'm stuck with several syntax errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Source:

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USR;1";
    String ERROR = Constants.PREFS_NAME;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private long period;
    private long delay_interval;
    String swappedMdn(Context ctx){ 
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        //Extract the phone number from the TelephonyManager instance
        String mdn = tm.getLine1Number();
        //Insure MDN is 10 characters
        if (mdn.length() < 10 || mdn == null) mdn ="0000000000";
        //Extract last 10 digits of MDN
        if (mdn.length() > 10) mdn = mdn.substring(mdn.length() - 10, mdn.length()); 
        char data[] = mdn.toCharArray();
        char digit;
        for (int index = 0; index < mdn.length() - (mdn.length())%2; index+=2){
            digit = data[index];
            data[index] = data[index+1];
            data[index+1] = digit;

    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");
        // super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (intent == null) {
            // Exit gracefully is service not started by intent
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: Null Intent");
        } else {

            if (extras != null) {
                text = extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT);
                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                        "//USR;1")) {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

                    Intent i = new Intent(this, DataCountService.class);

                StartActivity(i);  




                    // get the MDN





                            //Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DataCountService.class);
                            //i.putExtra("key", mdn);  
                        //tartActivity(i);  


                            Editor editor = settings.edit();
                            editor.putString("mdn", mdn);
                            editor.commit();





                    // get the date
                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "hh/mm/ss/MM/dd/yy");

                    String tag = ";";

                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String DToDevice = s.format(new Date());
                    String status = (settings.getString("status", "0"));
                    String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag + status
                            + tag + mdn + tag + DToDevice + tag, mobileStr,
                            totalStr + settings.getString("last_month", "0"));

                    info = "USI" + info.replace("USI", "");
                    // info = (info.replace("CN", "CO")).replace("WN", "WO");
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(info);
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("CN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("CN") + 2, "CO");
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("WN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("WN") + 2, "WO");
                    info = b.toString();
                    // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, info, null,
                                null);
                        // set status to enabled

                    //  Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("status", "1");
                        editor.commit();
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();

                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null, info, null,
                                null);
                    }

                    // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
                } else if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                        "//USR;0")) {
                    // set status to disabled
                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("status", "0");
                    editor.commit();
                    stopSelf();

                    // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to any other
                    // character
                }
                        }}
            }
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;

    }

    private void StartActivity(android.content.Intent i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private Intent Intent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {

            period = Constants.PERIOD;
            delay_interval = Constants.DELAY_INTERVAL;

        } else {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            period = Constants.DEBUG_PERIOD;
            delay_interval = Constants.DEBUG_DELAY_INTERVAL;
        }
        startServiceTimer();
    }

    private void startServiceTimer() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                if (settings.getString("status", "0").equals(1)) {

                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                    String tag = ";";
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String info = String.format("CO%s,WO%s", tag, mobileStr,
                            totalStr);
                    // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences

                    SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                    editor.putString("last_month", info);
                    editor.commit();

                    //

                    // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data usage)
                    // and
                    // save the current time
                    String sms = "";
                    sms += ("CO" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);
                    sms += ("WO" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                            .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                                null);
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();
                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                                null);
                    }

                }
            }
        }, delay_interval, period);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

ERRORS:

```
Syntax error on token "(", ; expected   DataCountService.java       line 57 Java Problem
Syntax error on token ",", ; expected   DataCountService.java       line 57 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName   DataCountService.java       line 51 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement  DataCountService.java       line 51 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "Intent", @ expected  DataCountService.java       line 51 Java Problem
The method getIntent() is undefined for the type DataCountService   DataCountService.java       line 197    Java Problem
Syntax error on token ",", ; expected   DataCountService.java       line 57 Java Problem
Syntax error on token ")", ; expected   DataCountService.java       line 57 Java Problem
```

ERROR NOTES:

```
Line 57 = public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
Line 51 = private Intent getIntent() {

Line 197 = Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

EDIT:

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USR;1";
    String ERROR = Constants.PREFS_NAME;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private long period;
    private long delay_interval;



    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");
        // super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);





        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (intent == null) {
            // Exit gracefully is service not started by intent
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: Null Intent");
        } else {

            if (extras != null) {
                text = extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT);
                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                        "//USR;1")) {





                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

                    Intent i = new Intent(this, DataCountService.class);

                StartActivity(i);  





                    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    //Extract the phone number from the TelephonyManager instance
                    String mdn = tm.getLine1Number();
                    //Insure MDN is 10 characters
                    if (mdn.length() < 10 || mdn == null) mdn ="0000000000";
                    //Extract last 10 digits of MDN
                    if (mdn.length() > 10) mdn = mdn.substring(mdn.length() - 10, mdn.length()); 
                    char data[] = mdn.toCharArray();
                    char digit;
                    for (int index = 0; index < mdn.length() - (mdn.length())%2; index+=2){
                        digit = data[index];
                        data[index] = data[index+1];
                        data[index+1] = digit;

                        //Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DataCountService.class);
                        //i.putExtra("key", mdn);  
                    //tartActivity(i);  

                //      SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                    //          .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                        Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("mdn", mdn);
                        editor.commit();



                            //Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DataCountService.class);
                            //i.putExtra("key", mdn);  
                        //tartActivity(i);  








                    // get the date
                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "hh/mm/ss/MM/dd/yy");

                    String tag = ";";

                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String DToDevice = s.format(new Date());
                    String status = (settings.getString("status", "0"));
                    String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag + status
                            + tag + mdn + tag + DToDevice + tag, mobileStr,
                            totalStr + settings.getString("last_month", "0"));

                    info = "USI" + info.replace("USI", "");
                    // info = (info.replace("CN", "CO")).replace("WN", "WO");
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(info);
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("CN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("CN") + 2, "CO");
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("WN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("WN") + 2, "WO");
                    info = b.toString();
                    // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, info, null,
                                null);
                        // set status to enabled

                //      Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("status", "1");
                        editor.commit();
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();

                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null, info, null,
                                null);
                    }

                    // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
                }   } else if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                        "//USR;0")) {
                    // set status to disabled
                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("status", "0");
                    editor.commit();
                    stopSelf();

                    // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to any other
                    // character
                }
                        }

            return String.valueOf(data); 
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }
    }

    private void StartActivity(android.content.Intent i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private Intent Intent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {

            period = Constants.PERIOD;
            delay_interval = Constants.DELAY_INTERVAL;

        } else {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            period = Constants.DEBUG_PERIOD;
            delay_interval = Constants.DEBUG_DELAY_INTERVAL;
        }
        startServiceTimer();
    }

    private void startServiceTimer() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                if (settings.getString("status", "0").equals(1)) {

                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                    String tag = ";";
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String info = String.format("CO%s,WO%s", tag, mobileStr,
                            totalStr);
                    // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences

                    SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                    editor.putString("last_month", info);
                    editor.commit();

                    //

                    // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data usage)
                    // and
                    // save the current time
                    String sms = "";
                    sms += ("CO" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);
                    sms += ("WO" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                            .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                                null);
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();
                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                                null);
                    }

                }
            }
        }, delay_interval, period);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

ERROR:

```
data cannot be resolved to a variable on the line: return String.valueOf(data);
```

Comment: Your IDE should tell you where the error exist

Comment: Indeed it does... (I posted them - I need help resolving them - I was told it was impossible to implement this method in a service - but I'm sure it's possible SOMEHOW - I just need a bit of help cleaning it up & configuring it so it will work)

Comment: we are not compilators. Your error output are pretty clear...

Comment: And where is line 57? Shall we guess?

Comment: I added additional details regarding line numbers : )

Comment: I see your error from here. It's clearly because you didn't read your code yourself to find your error...

Comment: Care to explain? (I've updated my source again too)

Answer (score 2):

Your problems start here:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < mdn.length() - (mdn.length())%2; index+=2){
        digit = data[index];
        data[index] = data[index+1];
        data[index+1] = digit;

private Intent getIntent() {
    return null;
}
```

You're trying to define method smack in the middle of a `for` loop. This won't work.

Proper indentation goes a long way to making errors like this almost impossible, I'm not even sure how you managed to code this in the first place.

Fix that first and several other errors will go away.

---

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");

    String swappedMdn(Context ctx) {
```

Again, you're trying to define a method in the middle of another method.

Comment: That resolved almost every issue I was having! Thank you! 

P.S.

There are only 2 errors left (I updated my source above)

Comment: @AmaniSwann The new error is essentially the same thing, you're starting random code artifact declarations in the middle of a method.

Comment: Apologies - I thought it would be fine after the OnStart command - any suggestions as to where I should place it?

Comment: Before it? After it? Everywhere I put it I'm getting errors from my IDE

Comment: @AmaniSwann It doesn't matter if it's before or after. The bottom line is that if you can't figure out where to put a method because of syntax errors then you need to take a step back and learn Java syntax.

Comment: I understand the basics of Java syntax - I just don't know how I can implement this in a service - I was told it cannot be executed in one - but I think it must be possible somehow - I just can't figure out how this can be modified to avoid those errors (I understand what is causing them - it's a syntactical issue - I just don't know how to resolve that syntactical issue)

Comment: @AmaniSwann Then I'd argue you *don't* know Java syntax, because forming syntactically-correct classes is much easier than forming *semantically* correct classes, and you haven't gotten over the first hurdle yet. Defining a method in the body of a for-loop is evidence enough.

Comment: It was an accident... I understand the basics (if I had looked at it longer I would have noticed it) do you really think I could have built the service (before implementing the new MDN swap functionality) without knowing the basics of Java syntax?

Comment: @AmaniSwann I'm ambivalent: that you turned around and made essentially the same mistake *again* would lead me to believe there's either Java or attentional issues. Making code syntactically correct is trivial, and IDEs make it even easier.

Comment: Mind helping show how I can resolve the issues I'm having instead of just saying "The IDE makes it easy." or "Learn Java". 

I understand the basics... I'm new to the arena - I've taken several classes, many many tutorials, built several apps - but I'm having trouble implementing a 3rd party MDN script into my existing service - but if you don't want to help me learn how to get past this issue - so be it

Comment: @AmaniSwann By what mechanism could I possibly help? You said "I  moved it above, below, and got errors." This is not helpful. If they're *syntax* errors, then you should be able to solve them if you know Java. If it's *execution* errors, then post the code, and say what the errors actually *are*. Come on.

Comment: The issue is occuring on the line String swappedMdn(Context ctx){ 

now I understand this is not agreeing with the code I've compiled thus far - you mentioned moving it outside the method - I have and I'm still having problems - if you aren't willing to help me learn how to avoid the issue - why would you even jump on a post for a syntax error?

Comment: @AmaniSwann You know I can't see your code, right? How could I *possibly* help? I "jumped on the post" because after you provided actually-usable information the first error was obvious. Your current error is *not* obvious because *I don't know what you're doing*. I don't understand why this isn't obvious. The code posted, and just the part in error, is ~150 lines with zero context, zero way to know what's supposed to be in which method, and why. The method is too long to begin with, and fixing it requires knowing more than we can simply *guess*.

Comment: I updated my source above - if it's of help to you and you can help me figure out a way to avoid the issues I'm coming across - I'd really appreciate the tip! (I just want to get this part finished already - I've built the entire service - I just need to byteswap the MDN and I'm done!)

Comment: @AmaniSwann ... Obviously `START_NOT_STICKY` isn't an int. I have no way of knowing what it is. Again: completely basic Java. Java methods must return the type they're declared to return.

Comment: I tried return startId; but I'm still unable to - I'm simply trying to implement the method to extract the MDN - String swappedMdn(Context ctx){ 
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        //Extract the phone number from the TelephonyManager etc


In my source code by any means necessary - this might clarify things for you a bit
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302281/byteswapping-an-mdn-within-a-service-in-android-impossible

Comment: I'm just not sure how/if this can be done (I was told it needs to be run in an activity but I need to byteswap the MDN in a service)

Comment: I resolved all the syntax errors - I only have one (non syntax) error remaining. If you (or anyone for that matter) could help me resolve it - I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @AmaniSwann Declare `data` in the proper scope: it's declared *inside a block* starting with `if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(...)) { ... }` and *is not available outside that block. That method is *far too long*. You also have two returns in a row, which is useless and your IDE should be hollering about it, and you don't have a return value for all paths: this won't compile after you fix the scoping issue. You're in over your head.